# Values won't change when I select on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a function which creates values for time as I am trying to calculate them, however when I try and change a drop down times I the values don't change as they just stay at 7. The function only loads the default values (time) which is 7 as it is 7 am.

As you can see from the screenshot when the form is loaded it has a time of 7am with the value of 7, but when I change the time to 8:00 it does not show the proper value of 8 and stays at a value of 7

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }

var timeStringToValue = function timeStringToValue(timeStr) {
  var _timeStr$match = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) ([ap]m)/),
      _timeStr$match2 = _slicedToArray(_timeStr$match, 4),
      hours = _timeStr$match2[1],
      minutes = _timeStr$match2[2],
      ampm = _timeStr$match2[3];

  var ampmHourModifier = ampm === 'pm' ? 12 : 0;
  return Number(hours) + ampmHourModifier + minutes / 60;


};

var startMonTimeStr = $('.start-time-monday option:selected').text();
var FinishtMonTimeStr = $('.finish-time-monday option:selected').text();

var startMonValue = timeStringToValue(startMonTimeStr);


console.log(timeStringToValue(startMonTimeStr));
console.log(timeStringToValue(FinishtMonTimeStr));
```

Comment: It would be alot better if you provided us with a demo of the problem, use the snippet tool `<>` to create the demo

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen not to sure if I can do that, as I am using wordpress with jquery So I have included a screenshot

Comment: Are you using onchange() function (or in jquery .change()) anywhere? If not, the code will just read the initial value set.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it and it works! Thanks.